# phpunit Functional Tests Failed getRepository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, phpunit

I'm running phpunit test but, I can't use getRepository to get $amount from my databases.

I don't know how to fix it.

I get this

> 1) Tests\BankBundle\Controller\BankControllerTest::testMoneyIn
>   Failed asserting that null matches expected 50

```
<?php

namespace Tests\BankBundle\Controller;

use BankBundle\Entity\entry;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class BankControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();
    }

    public function testMoneyIn()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->request('POST', '/bank/moneyin', array('amount' => 50));

        $query = $this->em
            ->getRepository('BankBundle:entry')
            ->getAmount();
        $this->assertEquals(50, $query);
    }
```

Comment: Could you check what connection you use with test-env, e.g. using the debug-command: `php bin/console debug:config doctrine dbal --env=test`? Can you add EntryRepository::getAmount()-method to the question as well?

Comment: @dbrumann thank you. I already Know why. It's not  ->getAmount() it's ->findOneBy